# How to fix GDM3 Login loop (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Tags: 16.04, login, gdm

I have 4 options for desktop environment:

- System default
- GNOME
- GNOME Flashback (compiz)
- GNOME Flashback (metacity)

If I select any of the last 3 I get in a login loop. However, if I select System Default it starts up only Nautilus (desktop icons) and from there I can open a terminal and run gnome-panel and metacity.

This problem started happening after I was trying to solve another problem: I uninstalled and reinstalled `plymouth` and `xserver-xorg-video-intel`. Not only did it not solve the problem, but I then couldn't login anymore.

Any suggestions to solve this problem? In which log files should I look?

I tried the common suggestions (.Xauthority, /tmp, reinstalling gdm) but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I did a few things but I'm fairly sure these are the lines that fixed my problem:

`apt-get remove gnome-settings-daemon`

`apt-get install gnome-settings-daemon chrome-gnome-shell gdm3 gnome-control-center gnome-session gnome-settings-daemon gnome-shell`

I have absolutely no clue why that is, but it just is. Just thought I might post so maybe some other people could use it.

If someone could explain it in the comments that would be awesome.

Comment: nope it didn't worked on me!